# PHP web app + web site same database but 2 users kinds

Tags: php, database-design, authentication

Im writting a RH system witch consist in two "services":

- Web App - For RH recruiting management companies
- Web site - For people and companies to seek/register CV

The two things use the same databases for all data... my question is about the users... im the WebApp, the user HAVE to be attached in a Company (my clients).. .but in the website... dont... just regular users registering CV and searching for a job!

How can i manage this two kinds of users??

I thinking in use two separate tables for each kind of user... this is a good aproach??

Tkz
Roberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are users, I'd keep them all in one table. Use a separate field, or a foreign relationship with another table to distinguish between the two types of users.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep all of the users in the same table, but for data that is "required" for users that don't have it, have a default "company".

Perhaps have a generic "company" that is called "Job Seekers". This would allow you to group all of the searching people without forcing you to maintain different user types (which becomes difficult to manage).